# Understanding instruction pipelining speedup calculation

Tags: microprocessor, computer-architecture, mips, processor

I was solving the exercise problem 4.17.6 of chapter 4 in the book Computer Organization and Design by Patterson and Hannessey (4th edition):

> Percentage occurrences of the instructions are as follows:
>   [image]
>   and following are the clock cycles sizes for different stages:
>   [image]
>   We can convert all load/store instructions into register-based (no offset) and put the memory access in parallel with the ALU. Assume
>   that the latency of the new EX/MEM stage is equal to the longer of their latencies. This change requires many existing LW/SW instructions
>   to be converted into two-instruction sequences. If this is needed for 50%
>   of these instructions, what is the overall speedup achieved by changing from the
>   5-stage pipeline to the 4-stage pipeline where EX and MEM are done in parallel?

The solution given is as follows:

> The latency of the pipelined datapath is unchanged (the maximum stage
>   latency does not change). The clock cycle time of the single-cycle datapath is the sum of logic latencies for the four stages (IF, ID, WB, and the combined EX + MEM stage). We have: 
>   [image]
>   The number of instructions increases for the 4-stage pipeline, so the
>   speedup is below 1 (there is a slowdown):
>   [image]

**Doubt**
I feel this is pretty wrong. The solution simply seeks to first find the increase in the number of instructions and then compare them. $$\frac{1}{1.15}=0.87$$However it neglects the increased clock cycles (from 200ps to 215ps) and decreased stage count (from 5 to 4). I feel it should be $$\frac{5\times 200}{4\times 215\times 1.15}=1.01$$
So there is indeed little speedup. Am I right?

Comment: They are comparing two pipelines, why do you thing the stage latency is modified between them?  What would be the interest of a pipeline if you had to take into account the number of stages as you are doing?

Comment: ok it seems that I made mistake and latency in both examples (a) and (b) is 215ps in both cases 5 stage and 4 stage pipeline, so we can ignore it, right? I don't feel it right to compare two pipelines if they don't have implicit matching parameters (here number of stages and cycle time), because both of them affect the actual execution time.

Comment: Why would the number of stages affect the actual execution time?  (Assuming there is no stalls)

Comment: Ohhhh I guess I was making mistake by considering time required to execute one instruction against instead of considering instruction throughput which stays steady as long as cycle time does not change... Am I right?

Comment: can you confirm that **(1)** we ignored cycle time because its same in both 5 stage and 4 stage pipeline. If it was not same we would have considered them in speedup calculation. **(2)** We ignored reduced number of stages because we dont consider instruction latency (time taken to complete one instruction) but consider instruction throughput (number of instructions completed per unit time).

Comment: Yes on both point.